# Focus working on chrome but not IE

Tags: jquery

I have a focus for the first elements on a form as long as they are Text Boxes, Password Fields and drop downs. I am having a Issue with IE at at the moment the Jquery is working find and as expected in chrome but not IE.

```
$('#pagebody').find('input[type=text],input[type=password],select,textarea').filter(':visible:first').focus();
```

I was just wondering why this is working in Chrome but not the IE. Thanks for any help which you can provide

Comment: can u give a jsfiddle demo link of your issue?

Comment: have you keep this code inside document.ready?

Comment: Not sure if related but you can use the `:text` filter to reduce a little that selector. http://api.jquery.com/text-selector/

Comment: Works for me, provided the elements exist when the code runs: http://jsfiddle.net/N2wtY/embedded/result/ Checked IE8, 9, and 11.

Comment: Cut this problem into different parts:
1) Check whether the .find returns items.
2) Check whether the .filter returns items.
3) I think one of above points will be the case.

Comment: I would simply say because IE is rubbish! but which version of IE doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : call jQuery code inside `document.ready` because IE calls `.focus()` method on fully rendered elements. See [this](http://www.mkyong.com/javascript/focus-is-not-working-in-ie-solution/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#pagebody').find('input[type=text],input[type=password],select,textarea').filter(':visible:first').focus();
});
```